# Variant array is 'corrupted' when running macro - Excel crashes

Tags: vba, excel, crash

I have a macro (code attached) which writes the data from two sheets into two variant arrays. It then uses a nested loop to look for all possible matches in the 2nd sheet on a piece of data in the 1st sheet.

When the first match is found one of the variant arrays appears to get wiped and I get a 'Subscript out of range'. this can happen when the data is being compared or when I subsequently try to pass data from that array to another procedure as a result of a match being found.

When I look in the Locals window, this array can change from showing the stored values to having the error message "Application-defined or object-defined error" in each index, or no indexes at all, or indexes with high negative numbers.

Regardless, if I try to investigate further while the code is in debug mode, Excel crashes ("Excel has encountered a problem and needs to close").

I have followed the advice at this link:
http://exceleratorbi.com.au/excel-keeps-crashing-check-your-vba-code/

...but to no avail.

I've stepped through the code and can trace it to the first time the data values being tested match. It happens for the same indexes (same i and j values) every time I run.

I'm using Excel 2013 on our office network.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this or any tests I could perform to help narrow down the cause?
Could it be due to memory use? The arrays come out at about 15000 x 11 and 4000 x 6 and it's the smaller one that is being corrupted/failing.

```
Sub classTest()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim CK_Array() As Variant, RL_Array() As Variant

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CK_Data As Worksheet, RL_Data As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set CK_Data = wb.Sheets(1)
Set RL_Data = wb.Sheets(2)

Call getRange_BuildArray(CK_Array, CK_Data)
Call getRange_BuildArray(RL_Array, RL_Data) ' this sets the array that gets corrupted. 

For i = 2 To UBound(CK_Array)
    If Not IsEmpty(CK_Array(i, 6)) Then
        For j = 2 To UBound(RL_Array)
            If CK_Array(i, 6) = RL_Array(j, 4) Then  ' array gets corrupted here or line below        
Call matchFound(dResults, CStr(CK_Array(i, 1) & " | " & CK_Array(i, 5)), CStr(RL_Array(j, 2) & " " & RL_Array(j, 3)), CStr(RL_Array(j, 1)), CStr(RL_Array(1, 3)))   ' or array gets corrupted here
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub


Private Sub getRange_BuildArray(arr As Variant, ws As Worksheet)

Dim endR As Long, endC As Long
Dim rng As Range

endR = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
endC = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Set rng = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(endR, endC))
arr = rng

End Sub
```

EDIT:
As requested here is the code to the matchfound Sub. It's a dictionary, which holds class objects in a collection. Therefore I have also posted the class code below. I'm not yet making use of all of the class properties and methods as this issue has halted my testing.

```
 Sub matchFound(dictionary As Object, nameCK As String, nameRL As String, RLID As String, dataitem As String)

Dim cPeople As Collection
Dim matchResult As CmatchPerson

    If dictionary.exists(nameCK) Then
        Set matchResult = New CmatchPerson
            matchResult.Name = nameRL
            matchResult.RLID = RLID
            matchResult.matchedOn = dataitem
            dictionary.Item(nameCK).Add matchResult
    Else
        Set cPeople = New Collection
        Set matchResult = New CmatchPerson
            matchResult.Name = nameRL
            matchResult.RLID = RLID
            matchResult.matchedOn = dataitem
            cPeople.Add matchResult
        dictionary.Add nameCK, cPeople
    End If
End Sub
```

Class

```
Option Explicit
Private pName As String
Private pRLID As String
Private pMatchedOn As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Name As String)
pName = Name
End Property

Public Property Get RLID() As String
RLID = pRLID
End Property

Public Property Let RLID(ID As String)
pRLID = ID
End Property

Public Property Get matchedOn() As String
matchedOn = pMatchedOn
End Property

Public Property Let matchedOn(textString As String)
pMatchedOn = textString
End Property

Public Sub MatchedOnString(datafield As String)
Dim text As String
text = Me.matchedOn & "|" & datafield
Me.Name = text
End Sub
```

Comment: by using `UBound(CK_Array)` you are trying to use a 2 dimensional array as a one dimensional.  you want `UBound(CK_Array,1)`.  but could you also post your matchfound sub?  And what is `dResults`?

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner and thanks for the response. 1) I was under the impression that Ubound's default position was to return the upper bound of the first dimension even in a multi-dimensional array. 2) I have edited the post to include all the other code you may need to see 3) dResults is a dictionary which I am using to store results data. It's defined in the class test sub (I removed reference to it here, to keep the post size down) and then passed to the matchfound sub.

Comment: Make sure the arrays are x,6 and y,4 as expected.  Debug.print ubound(CK_Array,2), ubound(RL_Array,2)

Comment: Hi @Jules, I've followed your suggestion and can confirm that after the two calls to the getRange_BuildArray sub, Ubound(CK_Array,2) is 11 and Ubound(RL_array,2) is 6. Shortly after that however, the RL array is cleaned out completely sas described in my original post.

Comment: The arrays are referencing to the worksheet cells.  Is there any other  process that delete/modify sheet2?

Comment: @Jules - No, nothing happens to the sheets throughout the macro. At the moment any results found are stored in various memory structures (class in a collection in a dictionary). Also, even if sheet 2 was deleted after the array was created, would the array not remain unaffected?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it creates a copy (i thought it was still referencing to the cells). Just a thought, does it have anything to do with the # of rows?  Can you try with 100 rows and see if the issue still happens?

Comment: @Jules I limited the loop control variables to 100. I also attempted only storing the first 100 rows of the two sheets in the variant arrays. The macro is still failing and still crashing excel. Thanks for the suggestion, I suspected that it might be to do with memory/resource issues operating within the company network, but this suggests it could be because of some kind of corruption.

Comment: I am almost out of idea, can you try debug.print both arrays and see at which row it fails ( for i= 1 to ubound(arr) debug.print i, arr(i) next)? Is it related to the data? can you try dummy data (2 chars only)?

Comment: Almost forgot, try on a different machine.

Comment: @Jules Thanks, I appreciate your persistance. I tried printing out the two arrays to the immediate window. It is always the RL_Array (the smaller of the two) that causes the code to fall over. I also tried the same having made a completely new workbook with dummy data on two sheets. Interesting development, when I just ran a loop to look at the RL_array I got a new error message before it crashed: Run-time Error 458, Variable uses an Automation Type not supported in Visual Basic. It only appears once, then after that it's the usual subscript out of range.

Comment: @Jules - Just managed to try it out on a different machine outside of the network (I think). The machine also had an earlier version of excel (2010). It's still throwing the same error though. However, I was able to get at  the Local/AppData/Temp files on the C drive and have a look at the WER report generated when Excel crashes. It doesn't mean anything to me yet, but I'm looking into it.

Comment: I am very curious with this issue as I can't replicate it.  Can you put error handling and debug.print err.description? Are your data static or calculated using formula?

Comment: @Jules - Please see the answer below. It always seems to be the simplest of things! Thanks once again for all your help, it was in trying out some of the things that you suggested that I found the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reduced your problem to a Minimum, Verifiable and Complete Example.

The problem occurs when you assign the *implicit* default value of a range to a Variant variable that was passed as a Variant array.

```
Sub VariantArrayWTF()

  Dim aBar() As Variant
  Dim aFoo() As Variant

  GetArray aBar
  GetArray aFoo

  Debug.Print aBar(1, 1)
  'aFoo() has now lost it's `+` sign in Locals window, but the bounds are still visible

  Debug.Print aBar(1, 1)
  'aFoo() has now lost its bounds in Locals Window

  'aFoo(1,1) will produce subscript out of range
  'Exploring the Locals Window, incpsecting variables, will crash Excel
  Debug.Print aFoo(1, 1)

End Sub

Sub GetArray(ByRef theArray As Variant)
  'Note the use of theArray instead of theArray()

  'Implicitly calling the default member is problematic
  theArray = Sheet1.UsedRange

End Sub
```

There are a number of workarounds - I'd recommend using *both*:

### Use Explicit calls to `Range.Value`

You can even make explicit call to the default member `Range.[_Default]`. The exact method isn't important, but it *must* be explicit.

```
Sub GetArray(ByRef theArray As Variant)
  theArray = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value
End Sub
```

### Avoid the use of `Call`, and pass common Variant definitions

- `Call` is a deprecated statement, and can be omitted.
- Declare the arrays and the helper functions' array argument consistently. That is, use () in all instances, or none.

Note the difference between declaring `Dim aFoo() As Variant` which is an array of Variants, and declaring `Dim aFoo As Variant` which is a Variant that can *contain* an array.

**With Parentheses**

```
Sub VariantArrayWTF()

  Dim aBar() As Variant
  Dim aFoo() As Variant

  GetArray aBar
  GetArray aFoo

  Debug.Print aBar(1, 1)
  Debug.Print aBar(1, 1)
  Debug.Print aFoo(1, 1)

End Sub

Sub GetArray(ByRef theArray() As Variant)
  theArray = Sheet1.UsedRange
End Sub
```

**Without Parentheses**

```
Sub VariantArrayWTF()

  Dim aBar As Variant
  Dim aFoo As Variant

  GetArray aBar
  GetArray aFoo

  Debug.Print aBar(1, 1)
  Debug.Print aBar(1, 1)
  Debug.Print aFoo(1, 1)

End Sub

Sub GetArray(ByRef theArray As Variant)
  theArray = Sheet1.UsedRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's been a while since I needed to look at this code as I found a workaround, but I've got some useful things to take away from your post.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the lines of code which were causing the problem. However, I cannot explain why it would necessarily cause a crash so I would appreciate other input on why this is happening.

When passing the RL and CK arrays to the getRange_Build Array sub I left out the brackets that would have denoted these variables as arrays.

The code was this...

```
Call getRange_BuildArray(CK_Array, CK_Data)
Call getRange_BuildArray(RL_Array, RL_Data)
```

...but should have been this

```
Call getRange_BuildArray(CK_Array(), CK_Data)
Call getRange_BuildArray(RL_Array(), RL_Data)
```

I'm thinking the reason that this didn't get flagged as a compile error is because the parameter in question in the getRange_BuildArray procedure itself also lacked the necessary brackets to denote an array.

It was this...

```
Private Sub getRange_BuildArray(arr As Variant, ws As Worksheet)
```

...it should have been this

```
Private Sub getRange_BuildArray(arr() As Variant, ws As Worksheet)
```

With those changes in place the macro is completing successfully for the full dataset and is not causing excel to crash.

As mentioned it would be great if someone could offer a more detailed breakdown of how this caused excel to crash.